# Favicon not loading in Chrome, after uploading to webserver

Tags: html, google-chrome, favicon

Currently I am having the issue of the favicon not loading on Chrome, after uploading the relevant files and code to the web server.

The code I have to achieve this is as follows:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/cdn/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/cdn/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/cdn/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/cdn/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/cdn/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/cdn/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/cdn/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/cdn/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/cdn/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/cdn/images/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/cdn/images/favicons/favicon-194x194.png" sizes="194x194">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/cdn/images/favicons/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/cdn/images/favicons/android-chrome-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/cdn/images/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="manifest" href="/cdn/images/favicons/manifest.json">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/cdn/images/favicons/favicon.ico">
```

Which was kindly generated for me by http://realfavicongenerator.net/

Does anyone know why this wouldn't show?

I have looked through the issues others have but am still puzzled by the favicon not loading in just this browser.

The site is running on HTTPS and the certificate is valid.

Any thoughts welcome.

Comment: Possibly try a hard reload (Ctrl + Shift + R)? Does it show after that?

Comment: Sadly not, nor in a private browsing session

Comment: Have you got a link that I can try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the BingMap `input`s to the body, as currently they are forcing the favicons into the `<body>`, hence they are not loading. Once they are moved the favicon displays as below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `/` before `cdn` or check the URL structure.